# FireFox not displaying CSS/Scripts/Images (anything from subfolders really) basic HTML site, IIS7

Tags: html, css, firefox, iis

Locally (outside IIS): Everything works fine across IE/FireFox/Chrome

IIS: Everything works fine except in FireFox. It doesn't want to load any of my subfolder content.

I've Googled the problem to death, thus...

1. Permissions are set adequately, (after all, it works in other browsers fine.)
2. The paths to the file are fine also. (Again, just FireFox.)
3. .css MIME Type in IIS is "text/css".
4. Static Content is checked under IIS features.
5. According to Notepad++, (Which is what the site was made with.), it is encoded in ANSI. (Tried others, no change.)

In FireBug > Net > All: It shows all but the page and a Google hosted script as "loading". In other words, anything local fails to load. (Which are all stored in subfolders in the root.)

DOCTYPE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

< head>

```
<title>My Website</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=9" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/clean.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/noscript.css" /></noscript>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 10]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/pie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/selectivizr.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Please, anything you can think of, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Locally (outside IIS): Everything works fine across IE/FireFox/Chrome is this means you only have trouble with firefox on your live site.

Comment: @AnkitGupta Right, but I'm running everything from one computer. I'm not hosting on another.

Comment: can u try giving the absolute path to these files and see if it works?

Comment: if you go directly to the URL does the page load? example: http://yoursite/styles/clean.css or http://yoursite/styles/style.css

Comment: firebug console show's no errors, scripting or otherwise?

Comment: @Robert No actual errors, it just shows them stuck in a loading-loop. (As described in the post.)

Comment: @Ber53rker Can you check the plugin or something you have installed in your firefox. one days I have a problem that ads.png not worked because of plugin thing it's about ads.

Comment: Does this have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Solutions:

1. Clear the browser cache. See if that works(It should work).
2. Use `~/` followed by path. See, if that works.
3. Lastly, use absolute URLs if nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the rewrite rules in IIS ? Using chrome do a right-click and inspect the properties of your page, go to Resources and check the links to your resources. If they were not loaded it's most likely a problem with the IIS configuration... Most likely a problem with the directory root, the rewrite (redirection) rules, or the permissions to each directory.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with Firefox where the css and javascript files are not getting applied
My solution was to add  lang='en' into the DOCTYPE i.e. `<!DOCTYPE html  lang='en'>`
Hope this helps